# Nginx Default Page being shown instead of the website

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, error-handling

While running the my flask app on nginx instead of the website page the default nginx page is opening. I am adding my nginx conf file here:-

[app.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cfyH.png)

error recieved from the log file: [error from nginx log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baL3O.png)

this all steps i did:

1. sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.conf
2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQEy6.png)
3. sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
4. sudo service nginx restart

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)